# Using string slice to show value on page load

Tags: javascript, slice, onload

I'm trying to extract the last 2 characters of a string to display on the page, and have tried string slice from w3schools, but want to be able to get it to display when the page loads, rather than using a button to execute the code?

The reason being is that the initial string value will be dynamically imported from a database, so the value will be different every time based on the users location.

I'm sure it's fairly easy but I'm completely new to this!

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "United Kingdom UK"; 
    var res = str.slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method is:

```
onDOMContentLoaded = (function(){
    var str = "United Kingdom UK";
    var res = str.slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
})();
```

This is good if you want to keep the logic without any inline stuff. It's basically a vanilla equivalent of jQuery's `$( function(){ })` shorthand.

Comment: Ah perfect thank you!

Now the tricky bit... I also need the result to appear in a code (delivery_country) that's being sent to Google, so will need it to appear in the code below:

 <script>
  window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          // REQUIRED FIELDS
          "merchant_id": 1111111,
          "order_id": "55555",
          "email": "anyname@hotmail.com",
          "delivery_country": "UK",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "2018-10-04",
        });
    });
  }
</script>

Comment: Glad to help! I noticed you haven't accepted any previous answers including this one - it would be nice of you to go and do so if the answers solved your problems, and also to let others with the same issue know what worked.

Comment: Thank you. I had previously tried to mark a question as answered but there was oddly no tick to click. Working now though!

Comment: Great. About your follow up question, I'm a bit confused with that so I'd make a new question about it without that inline comment formatting.

Comment: Thanks Matt I will do!